# Get contents of the selected cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my tableview, I have a list of about 500 items. User can search for their specific item. On click of the cell for the searched item, it will perform the `prepareForSegue` method. Example:

[image]

When user type in the search box "Ju" it brings June to index 0, and July to index 1. When performing the segue, if I select `June`, it will pass `January` data over. This is because it takes reference from the indexPath over. My problem here is how can I perform segue to pass `June` data over, instead of `January` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a copy of your data and filtering it, correct? so the indexPath '0' is correct for June in that data set. Don't access the original data set, access the filtered set.

```
var original = ["January", "February", "March", "April" /*, etc.. */]
var filtered = original.filter(/* some criteria, based on input of "ju" */)
```

And then when you read from it using the selected index path:

```
original[0] // "January"
filtered[0] // "June"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks so much! I was too focused on my programming. Oversaw this simple problem... XD